# How to discover the right source to solve a BUG in WSO2 DSS and build the product with this correction

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm facing a problem using WSO2 DSS 3.2.2, and try to correct the problem from sources, this topic isnt to focus on this specific problem, but is to ask anyone with experience in building WSO2 products to help other with the better way to do corrections in WSO2 code.

For this case, the problematic class is org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery, for the WSO2 DSS 3.2.2, that was distributed by turing chunck 13, then I checkout the sources using:

```
svn checkout https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk13 wso2-turing-chunk13
```

After the checkout ends, as my focus is only DSS I added to file in wso2-turing-chunk13/products/pom.xml on XPath //profile[@id='default]/modules the node dss/3.2.2, there exists all product modules commented, then instead to uncoment I just added new one.

To test the build and product distribution I run:

```
mvn clean compile install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

ok, now its time to find the SQLQuery.java to do the changes, for that I used:

```
find . -name 'SQLQuery.java'
```

That returns:

```
./components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/4.2.1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/description/query/SQLQuery.java
./components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/4.2.2/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/description/query/SQLQuery.java
./components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/4.2.3/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/description/query/SQLQuery.java
./components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/4.2.4/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/description/query/SQLQuery.java
./components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/description/query/SQLQuery.java
```

Now is the point I get confused and follow doubts appears:

Why have 5 diferent sources at same chunck?
If I do changes in any of these source no one are compiled in the product distribution, I tested the correction to check and tested too introducing a typo in the 5 source code above, and no errors occurs in compile time, I must configure something more in the pom.xml for one of these version goes to product compilation?

steps above based on: https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS322/Building+from+Source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These do not belong to the same chunk. They are for different chunks (but at the same location in components) and referred by their respective chunks in `product-releases` directory.

For patching DSS, you only have to build the relevant version. To find that, the easiest way is to check it in your DSS pack - go to `<DSS>/repository/components/plugins` and look for the version of `org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core` jar. 
Then modify the sources of that version of the component, build it and patch DSS.

Comment: ok, that worked, just more one doubt, you know why the deployed version was renamed with underline? as to work I must issue move org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core-4.2.4.jar from compiled to <DSS>/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core_4.2.4.jar